# ¿Por qué Angular Material no me aplica los estilos a los componentes?

Tags: angular-material, material

Actualmente estoy practicando con un Task List, pero a la hora de crear el componente Task que van a ser las tarjetas de las tareas no me aplica los estilos de @Angular/material.

Este es mi Angular.json:

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.scss",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

Este es el App.Component:

```
 <header>
  <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <app-tasks></app-tasks>
</div>
```

y este es el código de Task.Component que sería el componente de las tarjetas de cada una de las tareas:

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
<mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
<mat-card-content>
  <p>This card indeterminates progress bar.</p>
</mat-card-content>
<mat-card-actions>
  <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
  <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

Dejo adjunto una captura de como se ve actualmente mi proyecto.

[image: Task List Proyect]

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Has importado MatCardModule y MatButtonModule en tu fichero de módulo?

Comment: Hola Pedro! Vaya tontería... me faltaba por importar MatButtonModule... ¡Gracias!

Comment: Es un error bastante habitual. Me alegro de haber ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Busca sobre el encapsulamiento de estilos, shadowDOM y puedes encapsular el estilo para solo ese componente, sin necesidad de estar usando el !important.
Suerte.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).